# Recurrent sequence monotonicity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, induction

I have a recurrent sequence defined as $a_1={1 \over 2}, a_2=1, a_n={1 \over 2}a_{n-1}+\sqrt{a_{n-2}}$. It seems to be increasing monotonically.

I assume that $a_n \to g$. If this is true, then $a_{n-1} \to g, a_{n-2} \to g$. Plugging this back to the equation gives me $g_1=0, g_2=4$. All the terms of the sequence are positive, so $g=4$ is the candidate for a limit.

I am able to show $4$ is an upper bound by induction. Now, I need to show that the sequence is in fact monotonic, and I'm done. The usual way is to write $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$, where $f$ is some function which is obviously monotonic (so far I've worked with $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$), look at the first two terms of the sequence and then conclude by induction whether it is increasing or decreasing (or possibly stable). My problem is, I can't find an easy enough function of one variable. I have tried to show $a_{n+1}>a_{n}$ by induction but get stuck here as well. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If: $$a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}\leq a_{n+2}$$ then also: $$a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{2}a_{n+1}+\sqrt{a_{n}}\leq\frac{1}{2}a_{n+2}+\sqrt{a_{n+1}}=a_{n+3}$$

So $$a_{n}\leq a_{n+1}\leq a_{n+2}\leq a_{n+3}$$

And the expansion can be continued.

Answer (score 0):

For $ n<=4,\,\,√n > n/2$. So after $a_3, \, $ all terms are increasing, and as long as bound is 4, sequence is bounded and increasing monotonically. This happens because of the choice of initial terms.

Comment: I reached a similar inequality in my work. Namely, I tried to check when $\sqrt{a_{n-2}}>{1 \over 2}a_{n-1}$. However, $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$ need not be the same number. How can I relate this to your suggestion?